# Whats wrong with this SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

This query is giving me error so whats wrong with this query?

```
SELECT recipes.recipeId as recipeId,
       recipes.title as title, 
       recipes.cookingtime as cookingtime, 
       recipes.serving as serving, 
       schedule.catId as catId, 
       images.imagePath AS imagePath 
  FROM recipes 
 INNER JOIN schedule ON recipes.recipeId = schedule.recipeId 
 INNER JOIN images   ON images.recipeId = recipes.recipeId 
 GROUP BY recipeId
 WHERE schedule.day = 'saturday'  
 ORDER BY catId ASC
```

I think that the position of group by in query is not correct.

Comment: Although you were able to guess your answer (and have it confirmed by echo_Me), you should always include the error message as part of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking correct. `GROUP BY` should come after `WHERE` clause and before `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT recipes.recipeId as recipeId,
       recipes.title as title, 
       recipes.cookingtime as cookingtime, 
       recipes.serving as serving, 
       schedule.catId as catId, 
       images.imagePath AS imagePath 
  FROM recipes 
 INNER JOIN schedule ON recipes.recipeId = schedule.recipeId 
 INNER JOIN images   ON images.recipeId = recipes.recipeId 
 WHERE schedule.day = 'saturday'  
 GROUP BY recipeId
 ORDER BY catId ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

should be like that, where then group by , then order

```
      WHERE schedule.day = 'saturday' 
     GROUP BY recipeId

    ORDER BY catId ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Here without aggregate function you can't use `group by`.
and `group by` condition is after `where` clause and before `order by` clause.

```
SELECT recipes.recipeId as recipeId,
           recipes.title as title, 
           recipes.cookingtime as cookingtime, 
           recipes.serving as serving, 
           schedule.catId as catId, 
           images.imagePath AS imagePath 

    FROM 
           recipes INNER JOIN schedule 
                              ON recipes.recipeId = schedule.recipeId 

                                        INNER JOIN images 
                                                   ON images.recipeId = recipes.recipeId 

 --   GROUP BY recipeId

    WHERE schedule.day = 'saturday'  ORDER BY catId ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace order of

```
GROUP BY recipeId
```

after

```
WHERE schedule.day = 'saturday'
```

it need to be..

```
SELECT recipes.recipeId as recipeId,
       recipes.title as title, 
       recipes.cookingtime as cookingtime, 
       recipes.serving as serving, 
       schedule.catId as catId, 
       images.imagePath AS imagePath 
 FROM recipes 
 INNER JOIN schedule ON recipes.recipeId = schedule.recipeId 
 INNER JOIN images   ON images.recipeId = recipes.recipeId 
 WHERE schedule.day = 'saturday'  
 GROUP BY recipeId
 ORDER BY catId ASC
```